# Yii2 Page not found when calling country/index

Tags: php, yii2

I was practicing to work with Yii2 based on the tutorial in this link : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html

I am using Advanced Application
These are the files that i have created:

```
frontend/models/Country.php

frontend/controllers/CountryController.php

frontend/views/country/index.php
```

now when i try to access it using `index.php?r=country/index` i get **404 not found error**.
But if i move the `actionIndex` of `CountryController` to `SiteCountroller` and rename it to `actionCountry` and also move my view file inside site folder (and of course change the name of `index.php` to `country.php`) then i can successfully see the list of countries using the address `index.php?r=site/country`

Any ideas about the 404 not found error?

Comment: If you can access it via `index.php?r=site/country` after moving to another controller then probably application config is not the reason of problem. Check accurately names of folders, files, classes, maybe there is some kind of typo.

Comment: As i stated in my main description, i can move it to SiteController (and move the views to site folder) and then access it via index.php?r=site/country but what i want is to be able to access it via index.php?r=country/index which unfortunately gives me 404 even though i have double an triple checked the names and  ...

Comment: Please add content of these files. Also add your `urlManager` config.

Comment: Content of the files are same as the ones in this tutorial :  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html and i did not change anything about ulrManager so i am using Yii2 Advanced application defaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples in [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html) are for basic application and contains `app\` in namespaces declaration. And you are using advanced application so for frontend it should begin with `frontend\` (see for example [SiteController](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php) in advanced application).

I think this is the reason since you said that file content is exactly the same,  you didn't change default configuration and checked folders, files and classes for correct names.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. You are absolutely right. Now it's working ...