# Yii Controller Can't Find View

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Hi guys i try to go to http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=post URL but i watch **#404 Error**.
I use **yii** and I created a controller called

> PostController.php

.
You can watch my post controller codes here:

```
   <?php
       namespace backend\controllers;
       use yii\web\Controller;

       class PostController extends Controller{
       public function actionIndex()
       {
          return $this->render('index');
       }
    }
```

Also I created a **index.php** file inside

> views/post

You can watch **index.php** codes under this text

```
<?php
echo 'This is a test';
```

Comment: Are you sure your localhost points to `backend`? You've got `backend` in the controller's namespace.

Comment: Yes man if is possible you can connect to my system and edit code

Comment: If you have have you file  in yourdir/backend/controller/postController you  should use  http://localhost:8080/yourdir/backend/index.php?r=post

Comment: Read this,  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-applications.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 Page not found when calling country/index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344052/yii2-page-not-found-when-calling-country-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to modify your route with following?
    http://localhost:8080/post/index
where post is your controller name and index action.
Try to configure URL manager, adding some rules to handle route above. Yii 2.0 documentation is pretty extensive.
Check This http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-formats